# Google Compute Engine - LAMP Stack - How do I enable HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: google-compute-engine, lamp

I've just auto-deployed a LAMP stack on Google Compute. Before when I did this successfully I had to enable HTTP and HTTPS. Now it seems like they've changed the interface totally again.

**And this time I find the options to enable are greyed out.**

I tried accessing my phpmyadmin at [ip address]/phpmyadmin and it timed out...so clearly http and https are not being allowed in....

How do I enable HTTP and HTTPS access?

[image]

This is what it looks like right now. Not sure where to go from here as the option is totally greyed out.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the answer is to hit the EDIT button at the top.

I do express the opinion though that this is the most un-intuitive (yet glossy) interface I've ever used.

I suffer no shame!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

- Your instance is associated with the **default** network. Click on the **default** link.
- This will bring to the **default** network settings where you should review all the **Firewall Rules**
- Check if there are any firewall rules with tcp:80 or tcp:443 present for traffic. This will allow access from outside via http, https. If not, click on **Add Firewall Rule** and then provide access to those ports.

Alternately, you can also use **gcloud** to manage your firewall. Refer to gcloud firewall command example [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking?hl=en#addingafirewall).